# Restriction map on a compact orientable manifold without a boundary.

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I have the following problem:

Let $M$ be and $n$-dimensional compact oriented manifold without boundary. Let $p\in M$ be and point and let $M_p=M\backslash\{p\}$. Let $j:S^{n-1}\to M_p$ be the embedding of a small $(n-1)$ sphere around the puncture. Show that the restriction $j^\ast: H_{dR}^{n-1}(M)\to H_{dR}^{n-1}(S^{n1})$ is the zero-map. (Here $H_{dR}^k(\dots)$ denotes the $k$-th deRham cohomology).

I am thinking Stokes theorem, but seems like I can't quite get it right. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D \subset M$ be a disk around the puncture point whose boundary is the image j($S^{n-1})$. Then for any $\eta \in \Omega^{k-1}_{deR}(M)$ we have
by Stokes's Theorem (as you predicted)
$$
\int_D d\eta = \int_{\partial D} \eta = \int_{j(S^{n-1})}\eta = \int_{S^{n-1}} j^*\eta.
$$
If $\eta$ represents a cohomology class, $d\eta = 0$ so this expression must equal zero. In particular $j^*$ cannot send $\eta$ to a volume form.